# Getting a typescript error in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-select-search

i am getting a typescript type error in react-select options parameter in the componenet,

### ERROR:
Type 'readonly optionType[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'OptionsOrGroups<string, GroupBase> | undefined'.
Type 'readonly optionType[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly (string | GroupBase)[]'.
Type 'optionType' is not assignable to type 'string | GroupBase'.
Property 'options' is missing in type 'optionType' but required in type 'GroupBase'

```
type optionType = { readonly label: string; readonly value: string };

const [options, setOptions] = useState<readonly optionType[]>();


  useEffect(() => {
    const createOption = (label: string,value: string) => ({
  label,
  value ,
});
    if(userDetails){
    const tempArray: optionType[]=[];
    const tempVariableCrew = userDetails?.startList.tables.filter((item) => {
      if (item?.tableCode === "DFDEQUI") {
        
         tempArray.push(createOption(item.itemValue, item.itemCode))
        
        return item;
      }
    });
    setOptions(tempArray);
    setDfdCrew(() => tempVariableCrew);
  }
}, [userDetails]);


------------------------------------------
return(
<>
 <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue as string)}
        onCreateOption={handleCreate}
        **options**={options}  **//error here**
        value={value}
        classNames={{ option: () => "hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-md" }}
      />
</>
)
```

i tried looking into in but have not found anything substancial.

Comment: It says that you are trying to assign a value of type optionType[] | undefined to a variable of type OptionsOrGroups<string, GroupBase> | undefined. Could you be more precise and tell on which line the error occurs ?

Comment: @Fayeure there is a typescript error in the options parameter in the select component I have added stars to it, as you can see in the code I have defined the optionType in line 1 with label and value, as shown In the docs

Answer (score 0):

On your CreatableSelect component the `options` prop expects a value of type `OptionsOrGroups<string, GroupBase>` if provided, but you pass it your custom `optionType[]`to it instead, so if you replace your `useState<readonly OptionType[]>` by `useState<OptionsOrGroups<string, GroupBase>>`, it should work correctly, and you will see which properties are missing. If you still want to use your custom type for option you may want to look at the definition of the `OptionOrGroups` type to see what doesn't match with yours.